# Implications of Sharing an SSH Server?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, permissions, ubuntu-18.04

I operate an SSH server (Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS) in my basement that I use for backups of my laptop and several other installations in my house.

I also use it as a home media server. (Static public IP)

Recently, I've started conducting research into neurology at my university and our small research group (Consisting of several teams) is in need of a small server to centralize our work.

The university does not provide such a feature (Or ethernet jacks) and IT is... hesitant to allocate the resources and bureaucracy happened, so TL;DR we can't get a university located server. Funding is also tight, so our team leader (Who is also very untrusting of Google/Dropbox) is unwilling to pay for services such as Dropbox.

Assuming I have a security hardened server ([Security considerations when running an SSH server](https://superuser.com/questions/632725/security-considerations-when-running-an-ssh-server)), are there any security implications for my home network if I allow this kind of access to my research group?

NOTE: Potential loss of data is handeled by BTRFS + RAID 1 + External backups of the drive

I was thinking of creating a user (For example: hawk), which all of my research colleagues could log in as. It would have it's own encryption key which would be shared among the research group so that they could access `hawk`'s files.

The rest of the server would have `660` file permissions, denying them read/write/execute access to the rest of the filesystem.

Is there anything wrong with my reasoning of denying them access to the rest of the server using file permissions?

Could allowing my colleagues access to the server open vulnerabilities in my network despite them not having `sudo` permissions?

Could this access potentially breach the privacy of the rest of the server despite being restricted to only that sector of the filesystem by file permissions?

Could operation of the server potentially open me up to legal trouble if some (depraved soul) starts doing illegal activity using the server?

Comment: What you need is a controlled SSH environment. There are many such servers on Github, like this one: https://github.com/RaymiiOrg/boa-diminish-restricted-shell It's also a good idea to implement logging.

Comment: `Could operation of the server potentially open me up to legal trouble if some (depraved soul) starts doing illegal activity using the server?` - definitely. And especially since they are all sharing the same username `hawk` - there is no way to find out exactly which of the poor lost soul is doing illegal activity using your home network. So if someone going to knock on the door - the house owner is prime suspect.